# How to reset ng-select in Reactive Form through a FormGroup (AbstractControl) in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect, angular-abstract-control

I have a FormGroup with a bunch of ng-select elements. I also have the following code that resets all of the values in the Reactive Form except the ng-select elements.

```
  Object.keys(this.myFormGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    const currentControl = this.myFormGroup.controls[key];
    if (currentControl == null) {
      currentControl.reset();
    }
  });
```

I tried also `currentControl.patchValue('')` and with `null`, but it doesn't work. When I load a wrong "`item`" in the `ng-select` it has a selected value "`undefined`" and I want to clear this default selected value when it is `undefined`. That's why I use `== null`.

Even if you have a hacky JavaScript (Vanilla) solution, share it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass the initial value you want to reset the ng-select to; inside the reset function like so?

```
    Object.keys(this.myFormGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    const currentControl = this.myFormGroup.controls[key];
    if (currentControl == (null || undefined)) {
      currentControl.reset('');
    }
  });
```

I also added check for undefined control value too.

Comment: Yes. I tried, but when I reset it with '' or even null it still says undefined. The select is bound to ID, so I change the "selected item" with id like this: .patchValue(3) for example will select the item with id 3 and when I say: .reset('') it searches the item with id empty string I suppose. So no matter what am I doing, it always searches to select something for the "value" (id) I pass. The NgSelectComponent has a public method .handleClearClick() which removes the selected item/s, but I can't "access" the NgSelectComponent through an AbstractControl (FormControl)